# SQL - column has DATE, how to fetch data based "date" as one of the values in rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for an SQL query to fetch records from a table, for a particular date-format present in the column value itself.

The column uses the format:

```
num: num1:num2:yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss
```

Example values:

```
1928:52501:290c-1af6-44f2-8e3b-51ca4399
19282604:080:2901c-12-8b-51
997494:452:29a1c-1af-44-8e-51c99:2011-01-17 12:36:38
97494:452050:290c-1a-42-8b-51:2011-04-18 10:36:11
```

We need to fetch only those rows containing a date:

```
997494:452:29a1c-1af-44-8e-51c99:2011-01-17 12:36:38
97494:452050:290c-1a-42-8b-51:2011-04-18 10:36:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE to_date(substr(refid, -19), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') = TIMESTAMP '2011-01-17 12:36:38'
```

Of course you don't need to use "real" dates you can simply use

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE substr(refid, -19) = '2011-01-17 12:36:38'
```

If you want to find rows that have a valid date pattern at the end (instead of having *this date value "2011-01-17 12:36:38"*) then you need a regular expression to check it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM the_table
WHERE regexp_like(refid, '([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})$')
```

Note that this will not check for **valid** dates (it will return rows with "2011-02-31 40:50:60" at the end as well).

Comment: Hi...but it will only fetch results where particular date "2011-01-17 12:36:38" is present in the database. The rows can vary to some other date like "2011-04-18 10:36:11", "2011-03-19 09:11:20" etc...

Comment: @Ashish: you said *"I want to fetch results which has this date value "2011-01-17 12:36:38"* which is what this statement is doing. If you want to retrieve a range of dates or rows based on a different condition you need to provide more detailed information. Show us some real sample data (more than one row) and the result you expect from that.

Comment: Okay, here are some of the column "refid" values (separated by commas): 1928:52501:290c-1af6-44f2-8e3b-51ca4399, 19282604:080:2901c-12-8b-51, 997494:452:29a1c-1af-44-8e-51c99:2011-01-17 12:36:38, 97494:452050:290c-1a-42-8b-51:2011-04-18 10:36:11. So i need to fetch values with date only. So we sql will skip first values but will consider last two.

Comment: Please edit your post instead of posting this in a comment. So you want to retrieve those rows where refid contains a valid date string at the end?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rows with a date may be distinguished simply on the basis of the number of `:` characters in them, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table
WHERE INSTR(refid, ':', 1, 3) > 0;
```

You *could* then convert the dates to Oracle dates:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(refid,INSTR(refid,':',1,3)+1)
              ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
FROM   the_table
WHERE  INSTR(refid,':',1,3) > 0;
```

But then if any row has a value that cannot be converted to a date, the query would fail.

To solve this, you could create a function to test the value, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ref_date (refid IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN DATE IS
  d DATE;
BEGIN
  d := TO_DATE(SUBSTR(refid,INSTR(refid,':',1,3)+1)
              ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
  RETURN d;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Now you can query it as follows:

```
SELECT ref_date(refid)
FROM   the_table
WHERE  INSTR(refid,':',1,3) > 0
AND    ref_date(refid) IS NOT NULL;
```